# recursive reference in Perl

Tags: perl, refcounting

```
$a=\$a;
```

The book I'm reading says in this case `$a` will NEVER be free,my question is why perl interpreter doesn't fix it at compile time?When it finds it's pointing at itself,don't increase refcount.

Why perl doesn't do it?

Answer (score 6):

Some garbage collectors have cycle detection; Perl, for performance and historical reasons, does not. If you want a reference that doesn't affect the reference count, you can use `Scalar::Util::weaken` to obtain a weak reference, which removes the need for cycle detection in most situations where you would need to rely on it. There would need to be cycle-detection built into the interpreter to *automatically* detect whether `\$a` should be a weak or strong reference, so you just have to do it explicitly.

Comment: @Jon Purdy，how will checking whether it's pointing at itself cause performance issue?

Comment: @new_perl: Performing a check takes time, and the situation may not always be as simple as a single variable referencing itself. You could have a cycle across a very large data structure, which would require the cycle-detector to follow a very long and time-consuming path.

Comment: @new_perl That may be easy in your example, where a directly references itself.  But who would ever do that? Circular references in the wild are never as simple as $a=\$a .

Comment: @Jon Purdy ,can you provide an example of the complicated case?

Comment: @new_perl: `$ref = { foo => { bar => { baz => { quux => \$ref } } } };`

Comment: @new_perl most trees have references from parent to children and from children to parent: `$parent->{first_child}=$first_child; $first_child->{next_sibling}= $second_child; $second_child->{parent}=$parent;` This means that to detect the cycle you have to follow all the references in every variable reachable from `$parent`. You can have a look at Devel::Cycle to see how it can be done: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cycle/

Comment: @new_perl: Consider a hash `%h` where `$h{self} = \%h;`. Now, unless `$h{self}` is set to something else, `%h` will not be collected, and this is also true for more complex structures.

Comment: @Jon Purdy,so the problem is that when `%h` is dereferenced,its sub entries doesn't get the chance to be dereferenced,cause it may cause performance issue?

Comment: "else $a would be invalid immediately after the execution of that statement" isn't true, otherwise `$a = 4;` would be invalid immediately after execution too. A pad (lexical var) or symbol table (package var) would keep it alive until the variable's scope is exited, a which point Perl will freak out trying to free the same variable twice.

Comment: @ikegami .but self referencing happens frequently if you are developing some long running applications,how do you work around this issue?

Comment: @ikegami: We're talking hypothetically. If `$a = \$a` didn't increment the reference count of `$a`, assuming no other references to `$a`, it would be valid to collect `$a` immediately, just as if it were a temporary. In that case, referring to it again would (in a sane implementation of this hypothetical insane system) yield `undef`. That's all I was saying.

Comment: @Jon Purdy, By "assuming no other references", you're assuming a langauge other than Perl because that's impossible in Perl. The pad or the symbol table would reference it. `$a = \$a` leaves `$a` with a reference count of *2*, If it were *1* instead, the scalar still wouldn't be freed immediately.

Comment: @new_perl, [Object::Destroyer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Object::Destroyer) is useful when using other people's code.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, that aside, I've edited to be more clear, as well as adding a nod to @DavidO's answer.